# Got an error message of "'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character"

Tags: c#, sockets, utf-8, websocket

My code converts a String to bytes before sending:

```
byte[] requestByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);
```

XML is sent as bytes over socket:

```
int sentbytes = clientDAP.Send(requestByte, SocketFlags.None);
```

A response is retrieved afterwards from the host:

```
byteResult = clientDAP.Receive(responseByte, SocketFlags.None);
```

I'm trying to get it to give me a String output from the bytes:

```
responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseByte);
```

Further, I'm trying to load the response string as XML:

```
XmlDocument resultDoc = new XmlDocument();
resultDoc.LoadXml(responseString);
```

This gives me the following error:

> ***'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 1.***

The `responseString` is as follows:

```
<Response User="abc" Type="123" Timestamp="02/04/2016 05:12:25:504 AM" Subtype="TRADE" 
  Name="css" Logging="Yes" Echo="No" Client="abc123" Caching="Yes">
  <Output>
    <Reference>23324</Reference>
    <Client>GF23X</Client>
    <Source>2324ffd</Source>
    <Region>th</Region>
    <Status>ok</Status>
    <Message>Overall abc</Message><Message>Odef</Message>
  </Output>
</Response>
```

**Update:** I have seen all the suggestions in comments and tried with different encoding and decoding but nothing worked.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like it might have been serialized as UTF16 and deserialised as UTF8, or maybe something has serialized binary data into it. If you dump the received XML into a file, what does it look like? What if you look at the XML file using a binary viewer - what do the bytes look like?

Comment: what if you do responseString.Replace("&#x0;", "");??

Comment: @Matthew : updated i did in UTF -8 only

Comment: `byteResult` tells you how many bytes have been received. This may be as few as 1 or as many as will fit in `responseByte`. You cannot just assume that `reponseByte` has been *filled* with valid data, so passing it to `GetString` is wrong. Of course, if you've not received the full set of data, it may still be wrong to call `GetString(responseByte,0,byteResult)` since you might be especially unlucky and have received *half* of a surrogate pair at the end of the received data.

Comment: Got the solution Guys the problem here was i have taken responsebyte as 1024 and data was coming for some 340 bytes rest all the remaining bytes were getting converted into null \0 when i used responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseByte); so doing responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseByte,0,byteResult ); solved the issue

Comment: OP: If you've found the solution (as your comment suggests), you should post the fixed code as an answer so that your question doesn't appear as unsolved and lead others to attempt answering it.